# Execute link then redirect again

Tags: php, redirect, mybb

i've got a mybb board where I provide a certain link, looking like this

```
<a href="/member.php?action=login&do=switch">Klick</a>
```

The link changes the session and reloads the page, so I need it executed for the change in the session. However afterwards I would like to redirect the user to another page like "/private.php"

I've already tried different versions of combining href and onclick but it always takes me to the page stated in href, ignoring the onclick bit.
So my code looks somewhat like this:

```
<a href='/member.php?action=login&amp;do=switch&amp;uid={$others['uid']}' onclick='window.location.href({$mybb->settings['bburl']}/private.php);'>Link</a>";
```

I must say I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to javascript so I would need some help on that. I would like to solve this problem with javascript or php, so no meta tags, please.

Comment: As all of this needs to happen after the `GET` to `member.php`, after that point it's all down to the mybb framework. Editing for re-tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- In `/member.php?action=login&do=switch`, return a redirect response (http 301) to `private.php`, the browser will automatically redirect after receiving the response.
- Use ajax to call the link `/member.php?action=login&do=switch`, and in the callback of the ajax, redirect to `private.php` using `window.location.href = private.php`.

An example code using jquery:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"); //href here is "/member.php?action=login&do=switch"
  $.ajax(
  {
     url:href,
     ...
  }).done(function(){
   window.location.href = "private.php"
  });
  return false; //prevent default action of links.
});
```

Comment: However I struggle to make it work, though I can understand what it does. How would my html part for this look like? I've tried something like this: <a href="#" class="oc">... and then called the jquery part using $("a.oc") but that didn't work... (Right now clicking on the link will reload the page but not bring me anywhere)

Comment: @Senya: your `<a>` tag still points to your desired url like `<a href="/member.php?action=login&do=switch">Klick</a>` in your case. If you opt for the ajax solution, we intercept the click event and apply our custom logic in place of browser default behavior.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you I will try that out tomorrow!

Comment: In theory this is logical to me... However it just won't work in the forum. I think mainly because if I klick on the link the member.php adress does not appear in the adress line of the browser... I guess the reason why it doesn't work lies within mybb and I will try to find help in the mybb boards. Thanks for your help!